# How to create progress bar on top of google map

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, google-maps, progress-bar

How do I create a progress bar on top of google map in flex/as3? I tried to ask google maps API for flash, but no answer... May be some of you have done this already.

Thanks

EDIT: Can it be done using mx.controls.ProgressBar?

Comment: What do you mean? progress bar for which progress?

Comment: for progress of the map uploading and rendering. It takes time till the map shows up as whole. I wonder if there is a way to track the progress of map appearance. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Shaun from google maps API for Flash forum has answered this answer:
The secret is to enclose everything in canvas. This way one can put the progress bar on to of the map.

Here's the link to related thread:
[progress bar thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api-for-flash/browse_thread/thread/113c72aa2d352483)